# Gitlab - Using one self-hosted instance to deploy on several cloud providers?

Tags: azure, gitlab, cloud

Is it a 'good idea' to use one self-hosted instance of Gitlab (let's say on Azure) and use it to deploy on multiple clouds (e.g AWS, Azure, GCP) ?
What is first coming to my mind is that it needs a private network link between the cloud providers so that the private self-hosted agents can communicate with the self-hosted Gitlab instance.

I don't find architecture examples introducing this kind of solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not necessarily any reason why you cannot deploy solutions on multiple clouds, irrespective of where your GitLab runners happen to be hosted. Your runners don't have to be hosted in the cloud to which you are deploying. You can even deploy to all clouds from GitLab.com hosted runners, for example.

Comment: the thing is that I want to use private self-hosted agents as well to avoid CI/CD execution time's limit imposed by Gitlab licenses.

Comment: All I mean to say is that it doesn't matter where your runners are hosted. You can deploy to any cloud no matter where your runners happen to be, as long as they can connect to the internet @shako

Comment: yes ok got it. And apart from the feasibility, what do you think about the solution ? Would you do a centralized gitlab instance hosted in azure or aws or gcp and use it to deploy in every cloud providers or would you prefer to segment (spread runners for example) for security, network complexity, etc. ?

Comment: For simplicity, I would just deploy both gitlab and its runners in a single cloud/subnet. There may be other benefits of putting runners in other clouds, but it shouldn't be _needed_. If you wanted to deploy runners in every cloud, there might be a few ways to maintain connectivity to the gitlab instance. You might do a GitLab geo deployment with a GitLab node in each cloud and zoned DNS, you might connect your cloud networks using VPNs/gateways or host gitlab in a single cloud and make it accessible over the internet or tunnel @shako.

Comment: ok thanks for your experience's sharing. I mark it as resolved. Have a good day !